# Clearing Input in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm new to react native.

I've created a react native app and my first screen is a login screen. I'm using onChangeText to update state vars with username and password and this works great initially.

However on "logout" when I pop back to the login screen. The inputs still have my username and password in. However the state vars are now back to null.

I've tried setting value to {this.state.username} for the input but this just causes a depth error on state after 2 input presses so doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Alert, AsyncStorage, Linking } from 'react-native';

import { Input, Left, Spinner, Container, Item, Form, Header, Content, Label, Button } from 'native-base'

export default class Login extends Component {

    state = { username: "", password: "", isLoaded: true }

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super()
        this.state.isLoaded = false
        AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn").then(res => {
            if (res === "true") {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('List')

            }
            else {
                this.setState({isLoaded: true})
            }
        })
    }

    checkLogin() {
        if ((!this.state.username) || (!this.state.password)) {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Username/Password combination unknown', [{
                text: 'Okay'
            }])
            return
        }
        ....... snip ......
        if (response === false) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'Username/Password combination unknown', [{
                    text: 'Okay'
                }])
            }
            else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
                AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedIn', "true");
                this.setState({username: null, password: null})
                this.props.navigation.navigate('List')
            }
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        if (this.state.isLoaded == false) {
            return (
                <Container>
                    <Spinner />
                </Container>
            )
        }

        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Image source={require('../../assets/logo.jpg')}/>
                    <Form>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Username</Label>
                            <Input
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                clearButtonMode='always'
                                onChangeText={text => this.setState({username:text})} />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Password</Label>
                            <Input
                                secureTextEntry={true}
                                clearButtonMode='always'
                                onChangeText={text => this.setState({password: text})} />
                        </Item>
                        <Button primary onPress={_ => this.checkLogin()}>
                            <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your Code!!

Comment: @DevAS Code added, I haven't got the value={this.state.username} in the fields as that causes the depth issue noted earlier

Comment: @Kevin you'll want to figure out the depth issue - you do want to pass the `value` prop so the component works as a controlled component. Can you provide more information on the depth issue?

Comment: This is the returned error: ```Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but your `super` call in your constructor is not being passed `props` which if not related to this will cause other issues. Should be `super(props);`

Comment: Also when does the depth error occur? Immediately when you add the `value={this.state.username}` or after some interaction?

Comment: @azundo, for a second I thought you may spotted the issue with the super function not having props, but unfortunately not. The error does not happen immediately, it happens when you enter 2 characters in to one of the boxes, so for example if I just set the username one up to have a value of ```{this.state.username}```, when I enter 2 characters in to the username, this error pops up.

Comment: @Kevin I think the issue is here maybe:
`<Button primary onPress={_ => this.checkLogin()}>`

The onPress should be `() => this.checkLogin()` - right now I think `checkLogin` might be getting called on every `render` which could cause the issue.

Comment: @azunda again good spot, but alas no it doesn't fix the issue :(

Comment: Hmm, I'm at a loss then. I'm pretty sure your render function is not pure and is triggering a setState call which causes another render, then another setState, etc. But sure what else it might be.

Comment: I've added console logs into render and it isn't called repeatedly. Only on every key press.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem else where too it's literally if I have any input which I need to be able to control i.e clear or change

Answer (score 0):

You can use `direct manipulation` method.

Try passing `ref` to Input like `ref={ (c) => this._input = c }` and then calling the `setNativeProps` function `this._input.setNativeProps({text:''})`

Comment: What is _Input in this case? Would I need to initialise it in the class? I assume I'd need one for username and one for password. I will give it a go later.

Comment: It's a ```callback ref``` which is passed to the Input Component. No need to initialize, just use it in the component as described!

Comment: Get an error saying: ```undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._username.setNativeProps)```

Comment: You sure you're setting the ref correctly? And it should be mounted

Comment: I now have: ```<Input
                                ref={(c) => this._username = c}
                                autoCapitalize='none'
                                clearButtonMode='always'
                                onChangeText={text => this.setState({username:text})} />``` - I did a console.log(this._username) and it comes back undefined

Comment: If I add ```this._username = React.createRef()``` in the construct, and I console log ```this._username``` now I get ```{ current: null }``` - still doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Kevin how about you set values in ComponentDidMount as ```this._username.setNativeProps({text:' '})``` and don't use the ```createRef```` syntax, just the callback ref method, as it will give more granular level control.


Maybe, the internal implementation of ```<Input>``` of Native-base is different, so you can just switch it with ```<TextInput/>``` from react-native.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using react navigation and face similar issue.

I fixed as below :

import { NavigationEvents } from "react-navigation";

```
class ... {

onStartScreenFocus = ()>={
   this.setState({
    username: "", password: ""
   })
}

render(){
return(
   <View> 
   <NavigationEvents
                    onWillFocus={() => this.onStartScreenFocus()}
                    onDidBlur={() => this.onDidScreenBlur()} />
   <View> 
)
}

}
```